# Convert UINavigationController-based app to UIDocumentBrowser-based app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've been working on a `UINavigationController`-based Swift iOS app for the past few months, but I'd like to switch to a `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`-based app (or at least be able to implement it in my existing app). Is there a way to do this without creating a whole new project/target?

Comment: Do you mean UIDocumentBrowserViewController?

Comment: @matt yes. I shortened the title but forgot to spell it out in the question :P

Comment: Okay, so the answer is sure, you can do it without copying everything into the UIDocumentBrowserViewController-based app template project, but you need to look carefully at how that template project is configured, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this without creating a whole new project/target?

Yes. Make a new document browser based app so you can see how the project is configured, and copy its special features *carefully* into your existing project.

Comment: However, migrating your code and resources into a new project is also easy, so the fact that the thought of doing this bothers you is a Bad Smell.

Comment: it's not so much the code/resources as it is the storyboard interface. I've not had much success in c/p interface elements, and getting all of them correct was a headache and a half in itself.

Comment: You would just copy the whole storyboard right in. No problem.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use UIDocumentPickerViewController? If you implement this class in the section of your existing App then it should work.